# How many verb/adjective endings are there?

Tags: verb-endings, adjective-endings

Every time I turn a page of a textbook, there's a new verb/adjective ending. How many are there, and is there an authoritative, complete list of them anywhere? I found one extensive list, but there's no indication of whether it's complete, and there's no English translations, just the Korean endings, which either I know or don't.

Failing that, is there a reasonable list of *common* endings?

Comment: This question is too broad... But here is a [442 page book](https://www.amazon.com/Korean-Grammar-International-Learners-Bin/dp/8971415541) jam-packed with Korean grammar. There are easily hundreds of endings.

Comment: @Leftium I'm not sure the question as per the title is really that broad - after all, it's only asking for a number. I know some SE sites consider asking for off-site resources to be off-topic, though I'm not sure if we've talked about that in meta.

Answer (score 5):

In this [Korean endings dictionary](http://book.daum.net/detail/book.do?bookid=BOK00010848906BA&mobileYN=N) there are over 2000 endings.  That includes 조사 (noun endings), but most of them are 어미 (verb endings) or 어미 + dependent nouns (like -ㄹ 것이다).

Comment: Do native Korean speakers learn them all? If so, how?

Comment: I imagine most native speakers know most of them by heart, and they didn't have to learn them... Or rather, absorbed them from the environment. In fact, many native speakers wouldn't even know what you are asking about, they'd be like that's how we say stuff!